# Why don't half of us have situs inversus?

Tags: human-evolution

I don't see any possible evolutionary disadvantage in [situs inversus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Situs_inversus)(the condition where major organs are mirrored from their normal positions) when people with situs inversus can have a normal healthy life.

Comment: Can you expand this question by adding a definition of situs inversus and maybe some material that backs up your claim of no adverse effects?

Comment: if there is no evolutionary advantage or disadvantage then its frequency is only the result of genetic drift, given that it is a recessive trait (according to wiki) then it is not surprising it presents rarely.

Comment: downvoting because you give no reasonable justification for you assumption that a neutral trait should be present in half of the population. Also, some health issues appear to be tentatively (accroding to wiki) linked to situs inversus.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a faulty presuppositions (that situs inversus is completely benign, and that even neutral phenotypes should be evenly distributed throughout a population.)

Comment: During development, cilia in the node are responsible for defining the left-right axis and subsequent asymmetry. Situs invertus is often caused by ciliary defects, which disrupts this process. These defects can also cause lung defects and male infertility. It would also be reasonable to expect that whatever other molecular defects cause situs invertus would also effect other developmenal programs.

Comment: @canadianer - while situs inversus is found in diseases caused by ciliary defects (e.g. in patients with PCD, 50% aslo have situs inversus), not all ciliary defects cause situs inversus. Do you have a particular reason for saying "situs invertus is often caused by ciliary defects"? Just curious. I read a ton about this and never saw this statement.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Perhaps often was the wrong word. Situs invertus can be caused by ciliary defects. I was trying to make the point that, while situs invertus itself may or may not be detrimental, what ever is causing it can affect other processes and decrease individual fitness.

Comment: @canadianer - that, I agree with completely.

Comment: The condition is autosomal recessive so not only is there only a 1 in 4 chance that offspring to two carriers will be affected, it also requires two people with the genotype (heterozygous, unaffected carriers or homozygous, affected) to mate, and that makes the chances less likely. Also there may be many more carriers in the population, so the allele(s) responsible may be in the population at a much higher level that we are aware of... As even then 75% of the Heterozygous/Heterozygous offspring will have the phenotypically-dominant trait.

Comment: The homozygous genotype is not always benign. Your assertion that because the phenotype isn't in the population that the allele isn't in the gene pool isn't necessarily the case as carriers are phenotypically dominant, so the alleles could very well be prevalent. It is also a mutation that isn't always identified if the person does not have health issues, so its prevalence could be underreported. Finally, body plan genes are very powerful and as heterozygotes are phenotypically dominant it shows that there is no dosage dependence when there are functional copies of the gene present during dev.

Comment: Theoretically, a perfect mirrored body should be indistinguishable from the normal state and therefore there should be no effects whatsoever. And if there was no preference for left--right during development, half of us should indeed be "mirrored", as the title suggests. But this theoretical model is getting confused with the real condition situs invertus, which I guess is debilitating because the mirroring is in fact *not* perfect, so "conflicts" arise somehow. So it comes down to how the developing embryo can distinguish left from right, and how this goes wrong in the situs invertus.

Answer (score 7):

In the Wikipedia article linked to in the question, one will note that there are several medical conditions associated with situs inversus, including congenital heart disease, primary ciliary dyskinesia, and Kartagener Syndrome. These can easily lead to reduced fitness for reproduction, especially PCD/Kartagener Syndrome, as one effect is male infertility due to lack of functional cilia on sperm.

Therefore, there likely *is* a negative pressure on the alleles responsible for this condition, explaining why it is so rare.

Comment: When I was a post-doc my mentor used experimental manipulation to create the equivalent of situs inversus in C. elegans embryos. The embryos hatched and grew into "left-handed" or "anti-worms." He published that as a single-author letter to Nature in 1990, and had a series of grad students working on isolating mutations in handedness. It turns out that the main way humans with situs inversus are identified is at fertility clinics. Sperm motility is cilia-based, and functional Fallopian tubes have cilia that move the just-released ovum down to the uterus.

Answer (score 6):

If a polymorphism is neutral and has no effect on reproduction, it will not necessarily present itself to the population in a 1:1 ratio. For instance, for a single-gene polymorphism with two alleles in the absence of evolutionary forces like selection and gene flow, the trait will be at [Hardy-Weinberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Weinberg_principle) equilibrium, meaning the two different alleles will be present in some ratio (not necessarily 1:1) and will stay in that ratio from generation to generation. Of course, I'm not an expert on animal physiology and I don't know the genetic basis for situs inversus, but either way two equally fit traits may still be present in the population at very different ratios as there is no force pushing them to be present at equal ratios.

Traits undergoing [density-dependent selection](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18429672), on the other hand, such as sex, are under selective pressure to exist in a 1:1 ratio. There are unlikely to be any such forces acting on situs inversus vs situs solitus

Answer (score 3):

I am an eighty year old woman with Kartageners Syndrome.  This means, I have bronchiectasis which was diagnosed in 1948. The disease was isolated in my left bottom lobe. I also have chronic sinusitis. I think cilia is lacking or if not lacking at least too short to be effective.  For most of my childhood I was unwell but after age eighteen I seemed to be quite a bit better and I have lived a healthy life.  It is only recently that I have had health problems relating to Kartageners and I tend to think my age is now contributing to lung infections and therefore the quality of my life is deteriorating.

Comment: @AliceD Sorry, but this answer is on topic. [Kartageners Syndrome](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/299299-overview) is a disease associated with situs inversus, and I believe that the purpose of the post was to refute the claim made by the OP that situs inversus is benign.

Comment: @AMR - you are right. Thanks. I flagged this answer to alert the mods that they should be dismissing my previous flag. Thanks again.

Comment: @AliceD No worries. While I was familiar with situs inversus, I was not familiar Kartageners, but after looking it up, I got a clearer picture of the posters intention, and how often do we actually get to hear from someone who actually has complications from a 1 in 10,000 disorder (that is aware of it). It seems that the unfortunate thing for this poster is that it was partial and not total, as it seems that total reversal has the same phenotypic behavior as the majority of the population, except in rare occasions. It is only those partially affected that tend to have health related issues.